# Using the database index of choices in vb.net comboboxes

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, combobox

I have a question concerning indexing of choices in vb.net comboboxes.
Here is the scenario:

I have a database-table which is basically of the following structure:

```
| ID | Product | Property   | .....
---------------------------------------
| 0  | Fork    | Property A |
| 1  | Spoon   | Property B | 
| 2  | Knife   | Proberty A |
| 3  | Chair   | Property C |
| 4  | Candle  | Property B |
| 5  | Plate   | Property C |
```

and so on. I use the column "product" to fill a combobox in a vb.net application. Depending on some other choices, the user makes in advance, only products which have a certain property shall be shown in the combobox. I realized that which my sql-query and then I assign "Product" to the combobox. So far this works (I hid all the sqlite-stuff here):

```
CB.DataSource = sqlite.SelectData("Select ID, Product from table where Property = "Property A"  order by ID")
CB.ValueMember = "Product"
```

My Problem is now: How to store the selected value. I want to store the ID of the selected product in another table together with some other tings.
If I read the ID of the selected object using

```
id = CB.SelectedIndex
```

I get of course just the position in the combobox of that object, not the real database id. These numbers are the same when the property-filter is off but of course different, when it is on. Is there any simple straight forward way to read the corresponding database id out of the combobox or do I have to query for it before storing the value (that would be nasty although possible as "Product" has the "unique" flag.)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You should be setting the `DisplayMember` to "Produict" and the `ValueMember` to "ID", then getting the ID of the selected item from the `SelectedValue` property.

Comment: Hi jmcilhinney. OH! This is sooo simple :-) Thank you very much!!!